# Skip comma and other puncuation mark character from text content and replace it by space

Tags: c++, string

While working with c++ to do this we can scan entire content from first char to strlen(text)-1 and check for comma and puctuation mark. If char found then we can replace it with "space" or any other char.

```
for(i=0;i<str.strlen();i++)
{
    if(ch[i] == ',' or [other])  //assume I have copied content of str in ch[]
       ch[i]=' ';
}
```

But is there any C++ function or class which provide this functionality?

I am dealing with string, unordered_map, isstringstream, vector. Each has it's own functionality. But does anyone of this can be used for my above purpose? Or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can use:

```
//std::string input;

std::replace_if(input.begin(), input.end(), 
                 std::ptr_fun<int, int>(&std::ispunct), ' ');
```

Comment: @Karimkhan yes as per default locale see [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/ispunct)

Comment: Yes I checked it! Anyways do you know when favorite questions star is clicked?

Comment: @Karimkhan Ref: -[How do favorite questions work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/53585)

Answer (score 8):

You could use [std::replace](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/replace) or [std::replace_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/replace)

```
std::replace(s.begin(), s.end(), ',' , ' ');
std::replace_if(s.begin(), s.end(), [](char c){return c == ','; }, ' ');
```

see [live sample](http://ideone.com/ZRr7YC)

For C++03, could do:

```
#include <cctype>   
struct IsComma
{
    bool operator()(char c) const
    {
        return (bool)std::ispunct(c);  //!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~ as punctuation
    }
};

std::replace_if(s.begin(), s.end(), IsComma(), ' ');
```

als don't forget read [`std::ispunct`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/ispunct)

Hope this helps!

Comment: +1 May have to utilize [`std::ispunct()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/ispunct) or some such to get the full gambit.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the std string, yes. There is a [replace function](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/replace/). Here I can provide an example:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s = "The,quick,brown,fox,jumps,over,the,lazy,dog.";
    replace(s.begin(), s.end(), ',', ' '); // or any other character
    cout << s << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The output would be like this:

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
```

Comment: This will work for single test values. For a breadth of them (such as "all punctuation") a more involved solution will be required. But if all you need is a single shot direct replacement of *a* value, its hard to beat this.

Comment: @WhozCraig: Yes, I agree. Hope, I was somewhat helpful. :)

Answer (score 1):

You may use [`std::ispunct`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/ispunct) to check whether a char is a punctuation character:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string>  
#include <locale>         // std::locale, std::ispunct
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    locale loc;
    string str="Hello, welcome!";
    cout << "Before: " << str << endl;    
    for (string::iterator it = str.begin(); it!=str.end(); ++it)
        if ( ispunct(*it,loc) ) *it = ' ';
    cout << "After: " << str << endl;    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the old C-way of doing this. It's quite explicit, but you can easily program any mapping you want:

```
char* myString = //Whatever you use to get your string
for(size_t i = 0; myString[i]; i++) {
    switch(myString[i]) {
        case ',':
        case '.':
        //Whatever other cases you care to add
            myString[i] = ' ';
        default:
    }
}
```